# UIWebView centring page and allow navigation

Tags: swift, uiwebview

I managed to have a website loaded in my UIWebView but I can't manage to center it.
I also would like to be able to "navigate" into the website. What am I doing wrong ?

here's the code :

```
 import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var WebView: UIWebView!



    var URLPath = "http://google.fr"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        WebView.scalesPageToFit = true
        WebView.keyboardDisplayRequiresUserAction = true


        loadAdressURL()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func  loadAdressURL () {
        let requestURL = NSURL(string:URLPath)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL)

        WebView.loadRequest(request)
    }

}
```

And here's the IOS Simulator :

[image: Simulator]

Rob.

Comment: please post your question with the code it helps us to play with it.

Comment: The code is just above the IOS Simulator screenshot.

Comment: yes but I have to write it as cannot copy from screenshot to validate my answer

Comment: Just done it, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
       WebView.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        WebView.center = self.view.center
    }
```

Comment: When I click on a link on the WebView, the page is not centered anymore, any clues ?

Comment: if the entire Web-view is getting shifted or its alignment is getting disturbed you can use Auto-layouts to its parent view, it will solve your problem for all devices